# How could I clone/duplicate some sort of UIView for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

(screenshot below helps explain what I am trying to do)

The idea behind this is that I have a `UIView`, with various different `UI` elements inside, for example, let's say I have a `UIView`, and inside there we have a `UILabel`.

Now I'm wanting to duplicate the `UIView` (with the label inside) BUT somehow after that I need to perhaps make a change to the label, e.g. change the text property.

The reason I need something like this is so I can structure the `UIView` with everything I need in it looking nice, but to actually have different data with different copies of it.

I'm not certain this is the best approach, but it's the only one I could come up with. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, or any ideas on a better approach I'd really appreciate it. A lot![image: Screenshot to make it easier to understand]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very natural and useful thing to do. What you're looking for is a container view controller. Put your reusable "cell" into its own view controller and its own nib file. Then, in your parent view controller, use `addChildViewController:` to add as many of these as you'd like and configure each of them. They can each have their own IBOutlets that you can use to modify the contents.

This is very similar to the pattern used by `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` (it doesn't use "child view controllers" specifically, but it does use this pattern).

For full details, see ["Creating Custom Container View Controllers"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) in the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Note that Storyboard includes a "Container View" as an option in the object templates to make this even easier.

If you want lower-level access, you can also do this by hand using `UINib` to load the nib file and wire its outlets (and this is how we used to do it before iOS 5), but today I would use child view controllers.

Comment: That's brilliant! I think this is the solution! :D

Comment: From the design perspective, if it's a cell with a label in it, having a separate view controller for it sounds pretty much like an overkill (probably that's why UITableView doesn't do it)

Comment: I think for the final product I am developing there will be a little bit more than a `UILabel`. I'll perhaps need a couple of them, and a `UIImage`, maybe one or two other things.

Answer (score 7):

I personally think the best answer is to create each view separately and configure it as needed.  You can make a method that just configures new UIViews to look the same, and pass each view through it.

However, if you really need to copy a UIView, you can archive it, and then unarchive it:

```
id copyOfView = 
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:originalView]];
UIView *myView = (UIView *)copyOfView;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

If you have a bunch of these, make sure you're using the Instruments time profiler to check your drawing efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for that! Seems like a pretty cool way of doing it, so just to be clear, what you're saying is I create (and configure) my view, archive it, then unarchive it? Also could you link me to a resource or help me out with some code when it comes to archiving the view?

Comment: The code above is performing both the archive and unarchive. Note the use of "NSKeyedArchiver" and "NSKeyedUnarchiver" in the same line. This is the canonical way to make a deep copy of any archivable object.

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah that makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one label inside it the obvious solution is to have a custom UIView subclass with that label added as a subview. Everytime you need a new view you make an instance of your custom subclass and set the label text. If you have multiple things to set, some of which are common to all your custom subclass views you can use the prototype design pattern, it's pretty straight forward to implement.

Comment: Ahh cool! Yeah that sounds like a great way of doing it. Hadn't thought of it (still new to the whole iOS thing) I think I'll give this a try.